# Performance is sometimes slower

Tags: c++, performance

I have an app that launches, sends data to a server, then shutdowns.  Around 25% of the time that process takes double the amount of time to complete.  The network is closed off, and when I do similar tests with other software, the transfers always complete within a very short timeframe of each other, so I'm pretty confident it's an issue with my software.

I've done many, many captures with Performance Monitor and nothing stands out, other than everything just being slower.  For example, during a "normal" transfer, "% Processor Time" is around 7%.  During a slowwer transfer, it drops to ~4%.  Similarly, transfer speed is 55MB/sec when normal, and 30MB/sec when slow.

It seems like I've analyzed all data and I just can't seem to figure out what the root cause of the slowdown is.

Any suggestions, or tools that I might try to help narrow down the cause?

(The app is C++; runs on Windows 2008 and Windows 7, with the same problem apparent on both.)

Thanks!

Comment: You could only get 70% cpu utilization when you use more than one thread on a modern machine.  So if you are absolutely sure the drop can't be explained by longer I/O wait times then the next thing to do is to use a good concurrency analyzer to look for threading problems.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: Edit: sorry, I misrepresented the cpu utiliziation.  It's actually 7% and 4% instead of 70 and 40.  I had turned scaling on previously and forgot to turn it off.

Comment: You'll have to eliminate variables, for example try it on a different computer. If you're on a laptop it could be some power-saving thing. On wifi maybe the link is flipping between different speeds. Might be worth cracking out Wireshark to see if it is some weird TCP throttling issue. See if it happens with FTP too.

Comment: Hans, I'm not 100% sure that it can't be explained by longer I/O wait times, but my performance captures don't show anything unusual, and similar applications behave more deterministically.  For example, if I run robocopy using the same data, the results are very deterministic.

Comment: If your CPU utilization is that low your problem is surely I/O bound or due to other locking/wait mechanisms. Do you have some code for us?

Comment: filmor, I wish I did.  The codebase is fairly large and I don't know it well enough yet to give any succinct repro code.  Your mention of locking/wait is very interesting though.  I am going to look deeper into that.

Comment: A trick in this sort of case is to do some "stack tracing" - run the code up in a debugger, and "break", and see where you're at. You'll probably find that it's one particular function most of the time [it really helps to compile with "inline off" in this case, otherwise you may well find that your "lock" or "I/O" function gets inlined, and it's "all over the place".

Comment: An easy to use profiler: http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy